# Tensor product of elements in Hilbert space

Tags: tensor-products

I'm wondering if $E$ is a orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space $H$ and $E_0$ is finite subset, then is it true that $$||\sum_{e \in E_0} e \otimes e ||_{op} \leqq 1?$$

Iam reading this document [here](https://cdchawthorne.com/writings/trace_class_operators.pdf)

page 9. This seems not to be the case if I evaluate it like that:
$$
||\sum_{e \in E_0} e \otimes e ||_{op}=\sup_{||z||=1} ||\sum_{e \in E_0}\left<z,e\right>e|| \leq |E_0|.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Denote this operator by $P$. For arbitrary $z = \sum_{e \in E} \left<z, e\right> e \in H$ we have $Pz = \sum_{e \in E_0} \left<z, e\right> e$, so $$\|Pz\|^2 = \sum_{e \in E_0} \left|\left<z, e\right>\right|^2 \leq \sum_{e \in E} \left|\left<z, e\right>\right|^2 = \|z\|^2$$
and $\|Pz\| \leq \|z\|$. Therefore $\|P\| \leq 1$.

Comment: Aaa yes, this is a projection, and they are neccesarily of norm at most 1. Thank you